# Android - Passing string values for string in Alert dialog box

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alertdialog

I have setup an alarm for android where it also passes string values that is used for the dialog box. The first alarm that I set works, and it uses the string values that I passed. But for the following alarm that I set, it still uses the original string values that was passed.

I'm not really sure what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
//alert method from the MainActivity
    private void setAlert(int alertType, Calendar alertCalendar) {
        //identify which alert
        switch (alertType) {
            case 1:
                passFunction = "COURSE START";
                passValue = thisTermNum + " is starting on " + oldTermStart;
                break;
            case 2:
                passFunction = "COURSE END";
                passValue = thisTermNum + " is ending on " + oldTermEnd;
                break;
        }

        //actual alert
        AlarmManager alertManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlertReceiver.class);
        Bundle alertBundle = new Bundle();
        alertBundle.putString(PASS_ALERT_FUNCTION, passFunction);
        alertBundle.putString(PASS_ALERT_VALUE, passValue);
        alertIntent.putExtras(alertBundle);
        PendingIntent pendingAlert = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alertIntent, 0);
        alertManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingAlert);

        Toast.makeText(this, passFunction + " HAS BEEN SET", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is the receiver class:

```
 public class AlertReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

        //for passed values
        String PASS_ALERT_FUNCTION = "PassAlertFunction";
        String PASS_ALERT_VALUE = "PassAlertValue";
        String receivedFunction;
        String receivedValue;


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //receive passed values
            Bundle getAlertExtra = intent.getExtras();
            receivedFunction = getAlertExtra.getString(PASS_ALERT_FUNCTION);
            receivedValue = getAlertExtra.getString(PASS_ALERT_VALUE);

            //for alert sound
            Uri alertSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            Ringtone alertTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alertSound);
            alertTone.play();

            //to pass value to AlertActivity for the alert dialog box
            Intent passAlertValues = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
            Bundle alertBundle = new Bundle();
            alertBundle.putString(PASS_ALERT_FUNCTION, receivedFunction);
            alertBundle.putString(PASS_ALERT_VALUE, receivedValue);
            passAlertValues.putExtras(alertBundle);
            passAlertValues.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(passAlertValues);
        }
    }
```

This is the AlertActivity class where the dialog box will appear with the passed values:

```
 public class AlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        //for passed values
        String PASS_ALERT_FUNCTION = "PassAlertFunction";
        String PASS_ALERT_VALUE = "PassAlertValue";
        String receivedFunction;
        String receivedValue;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);
            setTitle("");

            //receive alert values
            Intent alertValues = getIntent();
            Bundle alertBundle = alertValues.getExtras();
            receivedFunction = alertBundle.getString(PASS_ALERT_FUNCTION);
            receivedValue = alertBundle.getString(PASS_ALERT_VALUE);

            //dialog box for the alert
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuidler = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertBuidler.setTitle(receivedFunction)
                    .setMessage(receivedValue)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AlertActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertBuidler.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the following line of code:

```
PendingIntent pendingAlert = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alertIntent, 0);
```

Use some other int value for the 2nd parameter, otherwise it will return the same pending intent. The doc says

> PendingIntent Returns an existing or new PendingIntent matching the
>   given parameters. May return null only if FLAG_NO_CREATE has been
>   supplied.

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) to know more.